# TestNG java валидация пин-кода

Tags: java, testng

Есть класс проверки валидации пин-кода

```
public class PinValidator {
    private final String pin;
    private final LocalDateTime dateTime;
    private final User user;

    public PinValidator(String pin, LocalDateTime dateTime, User user) {
        this.pin = pin;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public boolean verificationPinCode() throws AccountIsLockedException {
        int count = 3;
        boolean isExit;
        System.out.println("Введите пин-код:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!pin.equals(scanner.nextLine())) {
            count--;
            if (count == 0) {
                throw new AccountIsLockedException("Аккаунт " + user.getNumberAccount() + " заблокирован до " +
                        (dateTime.plusSeconds(5).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))));
            }
            System.out.println("Неверный пин-код, попробуйте снова");
        }
        isExit = true;
        System.out.println("Доброго времени суток, " + user.getFirstName() + "!");
        return isExit;
    }
}
```

Необходимо написать тест на проверку исключения. У меня тут организован ввод с клавиатуры в цикле. Читал, что можно сделать подмену типа такой

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = AccountIsLockedException.class)
public void pinValidatorShouldThrowAccountIsLockedException() {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("8888".getBytes());
    InputStream inputStream = System.in;
    System.setIn(in);
    pinValidator.verificationPinCode();
}
```

Но при запуске он у меня проверяет один раз и кидает ошибку, потому что это необходимо выполнить 3 раза. Подскажите как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если пин-код считывается из стандартного потока ввода, и требуется протестировать три попытки ввода неверного пароля с последующим выбрасыванием исключения `AccountIsLockedException`, для имитации ввода трёх неправильных паролей достаточно сформировать входной поток на основе строки вида `"8888\n6666\n1234"`:

```java
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("8888\n6666\n1234".getBytes()); // три строки с неправильными паролями
```

---

Однако следует отметить, что представленный метод валидации написан далеко не лучшим образом, в частности, с нарушением принципа единой ответственности и слабой логикой, так как здесь выполняются

- вывод сообщений с приветствиями в случае успеха,
- ввод пин-кода *из стандартного потока* (излишняя зависимость от способа ввода) с зацикливанием *пока не будет введён правильный пин*,
- допустимое количество попыток ввода и период блокирования не конфигурируются, а жёстко закодированы внутри метода,
- никак не проверяется период блокирования между последовательными вызовами
- либо всегда возвращается `true`, либо выбрасывается исключение, то есть возврат булевого значения не имеет смысла
- не проверяется формат пин-кода